# How to use customize assert marco

Tags: c

tmp2.c

```
/*
gcc -Wall -Werror -g assert.c tmp2.c && ./a.out
*/

#include "tmp2.h"
#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
    // assert(1 == 2);
    Assert(1 == 2);
    return 0;
}
```

tmp2.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdalign.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

/*
 * BoolIsValid
 *      True iff bool is valid.
 */
#define BoolIsValid(boolean) ((boolean) == false || (boolean) == true)

/*
 * PointerIsValid
 *      True iff pointer is valid.
 */
#define PointerIsValid(pointer) ((const void*)(pointer) != NULL)

extern void
ExceptionalCondition(const char *conditionName,
                     const char *fileName,
                     int lineNumber);
/*
 * USE_ASSERT_CHECKING, if defined, turns on all the assertions.
 * - plai  9/5/90
 *
 * It should _NOT_ be defined in releases or in benchmark copies
 */

/*
 * Assert() can be used in both frontend and backend code. In frontend code it
 * just calls the standard assert, if it's available. If use of assertions is
 * not configured, it does nothing.
 */
#define USE_ASSERT_CHECKING 0
#ifndef USE_ASSERT_CHECKING

#define Assert(condition) ((void)true)
#define AssertMarcod(condition) ((void)true)

#elif defined(FRONTEND)

#include<assert.h>
#define Assert(p) assert(p)
#define AssertMarco(p) ((void) assert(p))

#else
/*
 * Assert
 *      Generates a fatal exception if the given condition is false.
 */

#define Assert(condition) \
    do { \
        if (!(condition)) \
            ExceptionalCondition(#condition,__FILE__,__LINE__); \
    } while (0)

/*
 * AssertMacro is the same as Assert but it's suitable for use in
 * expression-like macros, for example:
 *
 *      #define foo(x) (AssertMacro(x != 0), bar(x))
 */
#define  AssertMacro(condition) \
    ((void) ((condition) || \
            (ExceptionalCondition(#condition,__FILE__,__LINE__),0))) 
#endif
```

assert.c

```
#include "tmp2.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#ifdef HAVE_EXECINFO_H
#include <execinfo.h>
#endif

/*
 * ExceptionalCondition - Handles the failure of an Assert()
 *
 * We intentionally do not go through elog() here, on the grounds of
 * wanting to minimize the amount of infrastructure that has to be
 * working to report an assertion failure.
 */
void
ExceptionalCondition(const char *conditionName,
                     const char *fileName,
                     int lineNumber)
{
    /* Report the failure on stderr (or local equivalent) */
    if (!PointerIsValid(conditionName)
        || !PointerIsValid(fileName))
        fprintf(stderr,"TRAP: ExceptionalCondition: bad arguments in PID %d\n",
                     (int) getpid());
    else
        fprintf(stderr,"TRAP: failed Assert(\"%s\"), File: \"%s\", Line: %d, PID: %d\n",
                     conditionName, fileName, lineNumber, (int) getpid());

    /* Usually this shouldn't be needed, but make sure the msg went out */
    fflush(stderr);

//  /* If we have support for it, dump a simple backtrace */
// #ifdef HAVE_BACKTRACE_SYMBOLS
//  {
//      void       *buf[100];
//      int         nframes;

//      nframes = backtrace(buf, lengthof(buf));
//      backtrace_symbols_fd(buf, nframes, fileno(stderr));
//  }
// #endif

    /*
     * If configured to do so, sleep indefinitely to allow user to attach a
     * debugger.  It would be nice to use pg_usleep() here, but that can sleep
     * at most 2G usec or ~33 minutes, which seems too short.
     */
#ifdef SLEEP_ON_ASSERT
    sleep(1000000);
#endif

    abort();
}
```

In this context, I'm trying a way to use the AssertMacro; that is, find a way to invoke assert.c ExceptionalCondition function. Assume FRONTEND is not defined. USE_ASSERT_CHECKING can be 1 or 0.

---

update: to use `ExceptionalCondition function` I need to declare it on  tmp2.h via

```
extern void
ExceptionalCondition(const char *conditionName,
                     const char *fileName,
                     int lineNumber);
```

I also need to define USE_ASSERT_CHECKING in tmp2.h or before tmp2.h.
If  I don't define USE_ASSERT_CHECKING seems all  the assert will be true always?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I don't know how to use the customize assert in main function. If in main I do `Assert(1 == 2);` It won't work. @Cheiron

Comment: What if you add something like `#define USE_ASSERT_CHECKING 1` before including  tmp2.h in main.c? You seem to imply that Assert is simply ignored, which would imply that USE_ASSERT_CHECKING is undefined. Also ExceptionCondition is not given as a function only ExceptionalCondition is.
Please update your question with all of this data, including the actual question.

Comment: @Cheiron now I seems get it. ExceptionCondition is a typo issue. now the question seems USE_ASSERT_CHECKING is defined the assert will always be true. even 1== 2.

Comment: @jian  Given code that does this `#define BoolIsValid(boolean) ((boolean) == false || (boolean) == true)`, I'd say "Don't use it!"  The only values a boolean can have are `true` or `false`.  That's like checking if an `int` value is an integer with something like `(INT_MIN <= (int)(n)) && ((int)(n) <= INT_MAX)`.  And using any type of `assert()` that crashes a program for a run-time error is a horrible **lack** of actual robust error handling.  Does "crash on unexpected data" really seem like a good idea? That approach sure didn't work well for Boeing...

Comment: @AndrewHenle part of source code, at least 25 years ago written by somebody. I just trying to understand the source code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's for debug_assertions. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-preset.html